# How to make space act like as if it were a new modifier key like alt, shift, ctrl

Tags: autohotkey

How do I make the space key (or any other non-modifier key) act like a modifier?

For instance when I hold down space and press h, it should e.g. print "hello".

Comment: You tagged `autohotkey`. Does this mean you want a solution specific to AutoHotkey?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a [**custom combination**](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#combo) of two keys by using " & " between them.

In this example

```
space & h:: Send hello
```

**space becomes a prefix key** and loses its native function,
unless you configure it to perform a new action:

```
space:: Send {space}
```